# Expected a smoothly fading opacity in this Raylib shader, but instead it is chunky

Tags: c++, shaders, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, raylib

In my main file, I create a regular icosahedron and assign the below shaders to it using the [Raylib](https://www.raylib.com/) framework in C++17.  I intended for the vertex shader to assign a 1.0 alpha value to points at Z=-5.0 and then linearly decrease alpha as points approach Z=5.0.  This did not happen, and instead I get the chunky results shown. I have a feeling that the problem lies with the vertex shader.  Can you see what I may have missed?

[image: This is not smooth at all, but why?]

**fade-test.vs**

```c
#version 330

// Input vertex attributes
in vec3 vertexPosition;
in vec2 vertexTexCoord;
in vec3 vertexNormal;
in vec4 vertexColor;

// Input uniform values
uniform mat4 mvp;
uniform mat4 matModel;

// Output vertex attributes (to fragment shader)
out vec2 fragTexCoord;
out vec4 fragColor;
out vec3 fragPosition;
out vec3 fragNormal;
out vec3 modNorm;

const float alphaMax =  1.0;
const float alphaMin =  0.1;
const float Zmin     = -5.0;
const float Zmax     =  5.0;

void main(){
    // Send vertex attributes to fragment shader
    fragTexCoord = vertexTexCoord;
    fragPosition = vec3(matModel*vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0f));
    fragColor    = vertexColor;
    fragColor.a  = 1.0*(Zmax - fragPosition.z)*(Zmax - Zmin) * (alphaMax - alphaMin) + alphaMin;
    
    mat3 normalMatrix = transpose(inverse(mat3(matModel)));
    fragNormal = normalize(normalMatrix*vertexNormal);
    modNorm    = vertexNormal;

    // Calculate final vertex position
    gl_Position = mvp*vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

**fade-test.fs**

````c
#version 330

// Input vertex attributes (from vertex shader)
in vec4 fragColor;

out vec4 finalColor;

void main(){
    finalColor = fragColor;
}
```
````

Comment: The main file is [here](https://github.com/jwatson-CO-edu/nanoverse/blob/main/C%2B%2B/Raylib/12-1_icos-colors.cpp).